# How do you reset localhost:8084 to http://127.0.0.1:8084 in Tomcat files?

Tags: apache, tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-7

I had some issues along with others, loading Tomcat 7.0.22.0 with NetBeans on packaged instal. This looked to be an issue with some computers and not others. Not to mention other little issues I got past, the browser would not load with

```
http://localhost:8084
```

So I pasted in...

```
http://127.0.0.1:8084
```

And it worked. The first address (with localhost) does work on my other computer and some others in our class, but a few have been battling with this. I figured out the patch by luck. The other problems (password and port #'s) also seemed to be consistent with possibly loading on a Windows 7 Professional 64, or this could be just chance. Any ideas would be a big help.

Comment: Note: I do not need to reset as my question states, more or less I just need to fix and understand whats causing the problem.

Comment: How many local network adapters do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing an entry in your hosts file. Localhost is almost always 100% synonymous with 127.0.0.1

Comment: in your unix box go to the root folder and type (minus the quotes) "find . | grep hosts" .. locate the hosts file and add (minus the quotes) "127.0.0.1     localhost"..

Comment: Not exactly the path I took but it was the change needed to make work. I co-classmate of mine (Eric Z) offered this path to change the file...1) Browse to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories
2) Right click "Notepad" and select "Run as administrator"
3) Click "Continue" on the UAC prompt
4) Click File -> Open
5) Browse to "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc"
6) Change the file filter drop down box from "Text Documents (*.txt)" to "All Files (*.*)"
7) Select "hosts" and click "Open"
8) Make the needed changes(for your tomcat port) and close Notepad. Save when prompted.

Answer (score 1):

localhost is (usually) found in the hosts file (on Windows usually found in `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`) when the computer tries to look it up. If the computer can't connect to localhost, it's usually because it's missing or configured wrong in that file.

That said, I've seen some computers having trouble with the ipv6 localhost line (the ::1)

Basically it seems to (on some computers) make ipv6 enabled programs like Internet Explorer use ipv6 while the non enabled ones use ipv4, which makes them not communicate. I've not been able to figure out exactly why some computers seem to have this problem, but removing the

```
::1 localhost
```

line and adding (if it does not exist) a

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

usually fixes the problem.

Comment: I am still running into problems. I was able to open  'code' <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
       allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"/> '/code` but that still does not fix the problem. I am digging in a haystack for a needle right now.

Comment: If you update the hosts file, you should not need to change any Tomcat configuration files to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

if you lazy here is best option

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9668866

**reference:-** http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972034